# Pass data from Python (flask framework) to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I try to pass data (exactly a path or a url) from flask to a javascript. But it don't recognize my variable.
On the server side: it upload a file, process this file and then create and save many images. When I try to pass the path to a javascript file which use three.js library it doesn't.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    print('coucou')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        print(file)
        # if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print(filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        path = UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename
        fits_reader = FitsReader.FitsReader()
        fits_reader.open_file(path)
        cube_faces = ['/home/morban/essaiserver/cube3D/CubeX.PNG', '/home/morban/essaiserver/cube3D/CubeY.PNG', '/home/morban/essaiserver/cube3D/CubeZ.PNG']
    return render_template('index.html', cube_faces=cube_faces)




for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                texture[i] = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('{{ cube_faces[0] }}');
                console.log('{{ cube_faces[0] }}')
                break;
            case 1:
                texture[i] = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('{{ cube_faces[1] }}');
                break;
            case 2:
                texture[i] = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('{{ cube_faces[2] }}');
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the data you need in a txt file and then accessing it via an Ajax call? It is a bit much, but if nothing else works, at least that we know will. Also, does flask have a scripting feature like Django where you can print the server-side variable in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript must be in the template file, and not included has script source.

If included, you can make it has a function or "class" and use it like this:

```
   (function($) {
    var texture = new LoadTexture(
                '#filter_form',
                {{ cube_faces | tojson | safe }}
            );
    })(jQuery);
```

you could/should pass cube_fase has json and filter it to safe on Jinja2.